# How to turn off default compression in Retrofit?

Tags: android, okhttp, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit for making HTTP calls. But it seems like the library is compressing (gzip) the request by default. Since the API can't handle compressed request, is there any way to turn-off default compression?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Retrofit does no compression. In fact, it's barely involved in HTTP at all as it just delegates the hard work to a real HTTP client.

That said, I'm going to guess you're talking about OkHttp, but OkHttp also does no compression by default. Adding request body compression is [one of the examples](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors#rewriting-requests) we provide. Since it's not supported by a large majority of webservers by default, it isn't enabled by default.

OkHttp will automatically add an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header to requests. This indicates to the server that OkHttp can read Gzip response bodies. If the server chooses to send a Gzipped response body (it doesn't have to), it will be transparently un-Gzipped before being handed back to the application code.